# Is possible to open another dialog box without closing the existing one in primefaces?

Tags: dialog, primefaces

In my application i have a primefaces grid and when click on each grid it will open ip a dialog window in details,but right now i need to close the popup window inorder to open the next one,is there any way to open other dialogs without closing existing dialog window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open as many dialog dialog as you want, only make sure that you gave them a unique `widgetVar` id:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg1">
    <h:outputText value="Hello from first dialog"/>
</p:dialog>
<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg2">
    <h:outputText value="Hello from second dialog"/>
</p:dialog>

...

<p:commandButton value="Open First" onclick="dlg1.show()"/>
<p:commandButton value="Open Second" onclick="dlg2.show()"/>
```

Clicking on the `commandButton` above will open two separate dialog parallelly.

Comment: Thanks @akoskm, in my case I have prime faces datagrid and there will be only one dialog being called on each click.content of dialog will vary based on clicked component in the grid,is there any property/script i can use

Comment: The [PrimeFaces- DataGrid](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datagrid.jsf) shows different grid item properties in the same dialog. If you want to open additional dialogs parallelly, see my answer above.